# How can I have my FFT peaks, exactly at the frequency of my signal?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I have seen the code below here but if you plot it and zoom it the frequency peaks are not exactly on 50Hz and 80Hz; they are a little bit off. Does anybody know why that happens? How can I make the peak be in exactly 50Hz and 80Hz?

[image: Figure - Peaks not exactly at 50Hz and 80Hz]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack

# Number of samplepoints
N = 600
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N/2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is the above plot with `N = 600`?

Comment: Yes, the plot is for the code above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple approximation error due to the fact that `xf` does not assumes the values `50` and/or `80`. If you change your `N` and/or your `linspace()` arguments, you can make `xf` to sample at exactly `50` and `80` and there you see no peak displacement:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack

# Number of samplepoints
N = 80
# sample spacing
T = 1.0 / 800.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2 + 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
ax.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2 + 1]))
ax.plot([50, 50], [0, 1])
ax.plot([80, 80], [0, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

with `xf`:

```
[  0.  10.  20.  30.  40.  50.  60.  70.  80.  90. 100. 110. 120. 130.
 140. 150. 160. 170. 180. 190. 200. 210. 220. 230. 240. 250. 260. 270.
 280. 290. 300. 310. 320. 330. 340. 350. 360. 370. 380. 390. 400.]
```

Answer (score 0):

The frequency of a pure un-modulated sinusoid only appears as a single FFT bin peak result if the sinusoid is exactly integer periodic within the FFTs length.

Otherwise, if the frequency is even a bit slightly different from the FFT's periodic basis vectors, there will be windowing artifacts, sometimes called "leakage".

If you want a non-interpolated FFT peak magnitude to be at exactly the frequency of your signal, then you will have to change the length of the FFT to be an exact integer multiple of the period of your signal (or change your signal frequency).

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that this has already an excepted answer:

If one needs to know the precise frequency of a peak there are simple ways without trying to trim the sample rate. How would you do that if you do not know the frequency you want to measure. So this would not be an answer to a displaying problem, but to a "real life" detection problem. Assuming that other peaks are "far" away there is a simple method with a Gaussian window. On a log scale, the peak will have a parabolic shape, such that the three highest points just provide the real position of the maximum. This can be transformed in a simple program solving just one linear equation. This is part of a class I use for analysing spectra:

```
    def get_base_frequency( self ):
        """
        uses the fact that the fourier of a gaussion is a gaussian.
        folding the virtual deltapeak of a frequency results in a gaussian.
        taking the log and looking at two consecutive bins, preferably near the maximum, 
        allows to calculate the position of the maximum, i.e. the frequency
        (square terms of the gaussians cancel and a linear equation is solved)
        """
        sigma = self.wavePoints / 8.0 ##my choice ... seems to work well
        tau = self.wavePoints / ( 2.0 * np.pi * sigma )
        pf, ps = self.spectrum_single_sided( windowType=[ 'Gaussian', sigma ] )
        ### fft providing freqency and spectral data
        n = np.argmax( ps ) - 1
        slg = tau**2 * np.log( ps[ n + 1 ] / ps[ n ] )
        better = slg + n + 0.5
        return better * self.sampleRate / self.wavePoints
```

That's it.

If the peak height is required, I'd suggest to make a second fft using a flattop windowing.